# How to calculate the distance between two points in SVG?

Tags: svg, transform, pie-chart, points

In the Pie chart, whenever a slice is clicked it has to be moved slightly as in the image.
 [This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlJmi.png)

How this can be done? What I am doing is,create a virtual arg with radius 10 higher that the original one. Then to find out the distance between these.

After the distance is calculated use the X,Y value to the translate(X,Y) attribute to move the arc slice to specified point

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="400" height="400" version="1.0">
    <g transform="translate(200 200)">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="150" stroke="#000" fill="none" />
        <path d="M0,-150 Q0,0 106.066,-106.066" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" />
        <path d="M0,-150 Q0,0 106.066,106.066" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" />
        <path d="M0,-150 Q0,0 -106.066,106.066" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" />
        <path d="M0,-150 Q0,0 -106.066,-106.066" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What I actually need is that, refer the below pictures,